# Ways to Detect Digits Not Zero in an int?

Tags: c#, .net

I was curious as to if there were any simple ways to detect the number of non-zero digits in an `int`/`long`. I want to create a small program that formats input(standard numbers) to scientific notation.

I've tried to find any `int` functions that could help do this, but I'm not 100% fluent and there weren't any that seemed like they would help.

Also, I want to find a way to put each digit from an `int`/`long` into a list with each digit being it's own element. Maybe there is a way from there to separate zero's from non-zero's.

Any fancy ideas (and comments) will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could convert the `int` / `long` into a `string` and then iterate through each individual character of it.

Comment: Just so you know, scientific notation can have 0s in the number. Its the trailing 0s that get truncated.

Comment: Both good ideas, I'll try them, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply turn it into a string (using `InvariantCulture`) and count only the non zero digits:

```
public int NonZeroDigits(int input)
{
    return input.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Count(digit => digit >= '1' && digit <= '9');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of non zero digits in a number

```
int NumOfNonZeroDigits(long num)
{
    int result = 0;
    while( num != 0)
    {
        if(num % 10 != 0)
        {
            result++;
        }

        num /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

print indevidual digits:

```
int num = 43546;

int digitNum = (int) Math.Floor(Math.Log10(n) + 1);

for (int i=0; i <digitNum; i++)
{
    int digit = (num / ((int) Math.Pow(10, i)) ) % 10;
    Console.Writeline(digit);
}
// the third dight would be: (num / 100) % 10
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, zeroes? What is a zero in a binary representation of an integer? When you turn it into a decimal value and print it to screen?

And if all you want is scientific notation, I would recommend having a look at [the MSDN-documentation for scientific notation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EFormatString)

Example:

```
var t = 1234.5678d;
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Will print something along the lines of 1.2345678E+004
```